# AudioKit 5 - player started when in a disconnected state

Tags: audiokit

Trying to use AudioKit 5 to dynamically create a player with a mixer, and attach it to a main mixer. I'd like the resulting chain to look like:

`AudioPlayer -> Mixer(for player) -> Mixer(for output) -> AudioEngine.output`

My example repo is here: https://github.com/hoopes/AK5Test1

You can see in the main file here (https://github.com/hoopes/AK5Test1/blob/main/AK5Test1/AK5Test1App.swift) that there are three functions.

The first works, where an mp3 is played on a `Mixer` that is created when the controller class is created.

The second works, where a newly created `AudioPlayer` is hooked directly to the `outputMixer`.

However, the third, where I try to set up the chain above, does not, and crashes with the "player started when in a disconnected state" error. I've copied the function here:

```
/** Try to add a mixer with a player to the main mixer */
func doesNotWork() {
    let p2 = AudioPlayer()
    let localMixer = Mixer()
        
    localMixer.addInput(p2)
    outputMixer.addInput(localMixer)
        
    playMp3(p: p2)
}
```

Where `playMp3` just plays an example mp3 on the `AudioPlayer`.

I'm not sure how I'm misusing the Mixer. In my actual application, I have a longer chain of mixers/boosters/etc, and getting the same error, which led me to create the simple test app.

If anyone can offer advice, I'd love to hear it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advice I wound up getting from an AudioKit contributor was to do everything possible to create all audio objects that you need up front, and dynamically change their volume to "connect" and "disconnect", so to speak.

Imagine you have a piano app (a contrived example, but hopefully gets the point across) - instead of creating a player when a key is pressed, connecting it, and disconnecting/disposing when the note is complete, create a player for every key on startup, and deal with them dynamically - this prevents any weirdness with "disconnected state", etc.

This has been working pretty flawlessly for me since.

Comment: Yes, that would work around running into your issue above. Still, I think it is worth spelling out to future eyes what to do in your scenario, because not everyone can have everything just "set up" from the start. I have music apps that absolutely must dynamically create and destroy nodes by the nature of what features they offer.

Comment: You can't attach audioPlayer -> playerMixer and then attach playerMixer -> outputMixer after the engine has started, but you can attach playerMixer -> outputMixer and then attach audioPlayer -> playerMixer while the engine is running

Comment: Is there an easy-to-explain reason for that?

Comment: I don't know for certain what exactly causes this problem, but I would say that once you have started the engine: work backwards from the output with your audio chain connections. So, your problem was that you attached a player to a mixer that was disconnected from the output. You needed to first attach the output to the mixer and then attach that mixer to the player. This is why I suggested swapping those "addInput" calls.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you can swap outputMixer.addInput(localMixer) and localMixer.addInput(p2) then it works

Once you have started the engine: work backwards from the output with your audio chain connections. So, your problem was that you attached a player to a mixer that was disconnected from the output. You needed to first attach the output to the mixer and then attach that mixer to the player.